# How to create nested class

Tags: c#, class, nested

I need to serialize and send someone a file. There are two types of struct which I will deal with, one is called trade and one is called quote. I am trying to nest them inside the class tickdata but I don't seem to get it.

```
public class tickdata
{
    public class trade
    {
        long time;
        double price;
        uint size;
    }
    public class quote
    {
        long time;
        double bid;
        double ask;
        double bidsize;
        double asksize;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you create the 2 classes Trade and Quote and give TickData 2 members, one of type Trade and one of Quote?

Comment: that a good suggestion. Thanks I will do it

Comment: Did my answer helped you? Then please accept. If not, do you have further questions?

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

```
public class tickdata
{
private Trade trade;
private Quote quote;
}
```

---

```
public class trade
{
long time;
double price;
uint size;
        }
```

---

```
    public class quote
    {
        long time;
        double bid;
        double ask;
        double bidsize;
        double asksize;
    }
```

---

Read more about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)

This is not C#-Specific, it is important for Object-Orientation at all

Comment: But why fields are private?

Comment: Provide setter and getter for the fields. Objects should not expose their fields directly to their environement. Read about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)

Comment: it's can be done like `public Trade trade {get; set;}`

Comment: Sorry, I'm coming from a Java Background :-) Do it like this, as it is the C#-Way. But keep the information-hiding in mind every time